# Walking around in circles

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Imagine you are an ant walking on a circle. You start your journey from the blue point. Your progress is given in percentages - 100% being a full round trip. In the figure, you've made a progress of 40% and reached the orange spot.

[image]

**If you're told the percent-progress of your journey (such as 40%), how will you calculate your current coordinates?**

You know these:

- Radius = 50
- Starting coordinates = (50, 0)
- Y axis is inverted - positive values are on the bottom (as in figure)
- Circle border has zero thickness

Comment: Should we assume the percentage is always an integer?

Comment: @Nautilus No, percent could be a fraction too.

Comment: There's an obvious solution, but I have a feeling that it won't be accepted as correct.

Comment: @Nautilus As Clint Eastwood once said "Go ahead, make my day"

Answer (score 1):

$x$:

> $50\sin\left(\frac{360p}{100}\right) + 50$

$y$:

> $50 - 50\cos\left(\frac{360p}{100}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

The centre of the circle is at $(50,-50)$ and its radius is $50$, so the general point on the circle is $$(50+50\cos\theta,50-50\sin\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the **polar angle**, i.e. the angle to our current position measured counter-clockwise from the point $(100,50)$.

We want our 'zero' position, or starting position, to be at the top of the circle and our direction to be clockwise, so put $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$. Now $\phi$ is the angle to our current position measured clockwise from the point $(50,0)$. So $$(x_n,y_n)=(50+50\cos\theta,50-50\sin\theta)=(50+50\sin\phi,50-50\cos\phi)$$ and this point is $\frac{\phi}{2\pi}$ percent of the way around the circle.

So the answer is: if you're $N\%$ of the way round the circle, then your position is

> $(50+50\sin\frac{2\pi N}{100},50-50\cos\frac{2\pi N}{100})$

(where we take all angles in radians).

Comment: Are you sure, shouldn't there be a 100 in there somewhere?

Comment: Since the y axis is inverted, shouldn't the center be at (50, 50)?

Comment: @Nautilus Good point; I missed that. I'll edit.

Comment: @RenaeLider Should there? The centre's at (50,50) and we move out from there - where would 100 come from?

Comment: @RenaeLider Oh, you mean inside the brackets? Another good point - edited once more.

Comment: You answered the question, then voted to close it as *off-topic*?